# Mobile Bootstrap Carousel - Font resizing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've added a simply bootstrap 4 carousel to a site I'm working on and the carousel itself is working as it should.

When I inspect the site on my mobile device (Galaxy S8+) and scroll down to the bootstrap carousel, the font size is initially correct but then enlarges as I scroll through each carousel item.

My question is, could the phones screen resolution or pixel density be causing this issue? I have also looked at the site on an Iphone4 and Iphone7 and the font doesn't enlarge, which is want I want.

I have media queries that adjust the paragraph height so the container doesn't resize when the user scrolls to a different carousel item

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .testimonial-text {
        min-height: 185px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .testimonial-text {
        min-height: 215px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .testimonial-text {
        min-height: 215px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:522px) {
    .testimonial-text {
        min-height: 240px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:456px) {
    .testimonial-text {
        min-height: 265px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:413px) {
    .testimonial-text {
        min-height: 315px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:368px) {
    .testimonial-text {
        min-height: 375px;
    }
}
```

This is a carousel for testimonials and the font size for the paragraph tag I'm using is set at 16px, and like I had said before - initially, before moving to the second carousel item, the font size looks correct. Once I move to the next carousel item the font size jumps up a couple pixels. Between carousel item transitions the font size looks correct but once the transition stops the font size jumps back up. It stays like this once the carousel has been instantiated.

to reiterate this is only on my mobile device.

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/a92ys80v/20/

Thanks in advance for any input. I'd be happy to give more information as well.

Comment: Please add a [mcve], so that we can try this out.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle of the carousel. When I go to the jsfiddle carousel on my phone it does not have the same issue that is present on my testing site.

Comment: If it doesn't happen in the fiddle, then the problem is somewhere in the code that you did not add to the fiddle. Is there any other stylesheet or script being loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what do you want but if you want to reduce the font-size or provide any style for mobile/devices you can write the media query for that device width something like this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

for more information  visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: I will edit my question. I'm not looking to set media queries, I've already done this for the carousel